# Communication between Socket Class and UI

Tags: java, android, sockets, user-interface, handler

I am developing an android application that needs to transmit some data through sockets. At this moment it connects to the socket, send messages when clicking the interface buttons, but I want to alert the user with a AlertDialog on my interface when the socket class receives a message. I've been searching and found information about Handlers but I could not use them. How can I solve this problem?
Thanks

Comment: `send messages through interface buttons`??? `socket class receives a message with a method AlertDialog`????? What is the problem???

Comment: Sorry for my poor english, I edited and tried to make it better now. Thanks

Comment: If you can display an AlertDialog then what is the problem exactly?

Comment: Thats the point, i can't call an alertdialog because my socket thread isn't on my main activity (UI).

Comment: Then you can use Runnable and Handler. Or runOnUiThread();

Comment: Like I wrote on my ask, i couldn't use that.

Comment: What makes you so certain?

Comment: Because it doesn't compile?!

Comment: Who said that? Give more info please.

Comment: Okay, supposing I am trying to use the runOnUiThread like on the first answer. On my socket class (ins't a inner class) when calling MapPane.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){...} the Android Studio says "this" is unexpected token (Mappane is my main activity class).

Comment: Cannot you get a Context from somewhere?

Comment: Sorry, i don't know how to do. :(

Comment: If you start your thread/service then give it an extra parameter context which is that main activity.

Comment: I passed a parameter on the socket constructor and tried to write that method, it didn't work anyway.

Comment: How do you think we can solve your problem?

Comment: Actually, I am trying to receive the data from socket connections on a thread on my socket class that updates a variable from my main activity and another thread on main activity verify if that variable is different of null. But my app crashes everytime i call that method.

Answer (score 1):

```
MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // Build an alert dialog
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setTitle("Title")
                .setMessage("Message")
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton("Done", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                        // Close the dialog
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                  });

        // Create the alert dialog
        AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();

        // Show the alert dialog
        alertDialog.show();
    }
});
```